# Finding radius of convergence without cauchy ratio test

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently taking a differential equations course and we are learning about second order homogeneous equations and finding the general solution using series.

I noticed during lecture, that sometimes my professor is able to find the radius of convergence without using cauchy ratio test.

For example, I noted down this equation:

$$ y''-2ty'+\lambda y=0$$

where $\lambda$ is a fixed constant. My professor said $2t$ and $\lambda$ are both polynomials, so the equation converges everywhere. Keep in mind that my professor speaks a bit fast, so I could have mistaken what he said above.

Also, I would ask my professor but he does not like answering questions.

There are times where my professor does use the ratio test but my question is:

**How can we determine the radius of convergence without using the cauchy ratio test? I know there shall be times where you have to use the ratio test but I would like to know the cases in which you can determine the radius of convergence by just looking at the equation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theorem which answers this: (I summarize from the book [Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470458313))

> Consider the second-order ode $y'' + p(t)y' + q(t) y = 0$.
>
> If $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are ***analytic*** at a point $t_0$ (that is, the Taylor series expansions of $p$ and $q$ around $t_0$ converges to $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, respectively, in some interval around $t_0$) , then the general solution is given by
>   \begin{equation}
> y(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_n(t - t_0)^n = a_0y_1(t) + a_1 y_2(t)
> \end{equation}
>   where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are arbitrary constants, and $y_1$, $y_2$ form a fundamental set of solutions.
>
> **Furthermore, the radius of convergence for each of the series $y_1$ and $y_2$ is at least as large as the minimum of the radii of convergence of the series for $p$ and $q$.**

In your example above, $p(t) = -2t$ and $q(t) = \lambda$ are polynomials, so analytic at every $t_0$ with infinite radius of convergence. Hence the solution $y(t)$ has infinite radius of convergence, i.e., converges everywhere.

Comment: How about in the example $(1-t^2)y''-ty'+\alpha^2 y=0$ where $\alpha^2$ is a fixed constant. $p(t)=-t$ and $q(t)=\alpha^2$ which I believe are both polynomials but I was told that $p$ and $q$ have convergence of $1$, shouldn't it be infinite?

Comment: That ODE is not in the form $y'' + p(t) y' + q(t)y = 0$: we need to divide by $(1-t^2)$ (here we are solving around $t = 0$, so this is okay) to get $y'' - \frac{t}{1-t^2}y' +\frac{\alpha^2}{1-t^2}y = 0$. Then as $p(t) = - \frac{t}{1-t^2}$ and $q(t) = \frac{\alpha^2}{1-t^2}$ both have radius of convergence $1$ around $t = 0$, we know the solution $y(t)$ also has radius of convergence $1$ around $t = 0$ (by the theorem above).

Comment: makes sense now. thanks for being super helpful!